# Python re.match CSV writer

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, csv

I am using Python to Read/Write a .CSV file.

But the data sometimes has blank columns.

I want to handle the blank columns and paste data from another column instead.

When it's blank it currently looks like this:

```
250,,0
```

When it is not blank:

```
250,TextHere,0
```

This is my current attempt at a solution:

```
if re.match in ("\w", row[5]):
    RT=row[5]
else:
    RT='Comment'
outRow.append(RT)
```

Can anyone explain how I could do this ?

Comment: So whats the issue you have?

Comment: I am unable to tell Python when a blank is present which is represented in the csv file as ,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.match in ("\w", row[5])
```

checks if the method `re.match` is either the string `"\w"` or identical to the value `row[5]` (which is probably also a string, although you are not revealing how this is initialized); which of course it will never be - a method is a method, not a string; in order for something to be equal to a string, this too would have to be a string as well (or at least have a meaningful representation as a string).

The way to check if `row[5]` matches your regex would be

```
re.match(r'\w', row[5])
```

but as noted in a previous answer, you really don't want or need to use a regex here.

```
if row[5] != '':
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple `if-else` check.

**Ex:**

```
RT = row[5] if row[5].strip() else 'Comment'
outRow.append(RT)
```

Looks like you do not need regex here